# React Native WhiteLabel Application

Tags: android, ios, react-native, babeljs, mobile-development

I am trying to implement a white-label application in react native where I could build and bundle an app without importing "everything" from the project.

For example, I might have `assets_app1` folder weigh 10MB and `assets_app2` weigh 1MB. I get always 11mb in the end, regardless of what project I am compiling and bundling for production.

I have checked multiple sources on how to build white-label with `flavours` and `targets` on Android and iOS respectively, looked up [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver), but wasn't able to find and build a perfect solution.

The best I could find is [this solution](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/white-label-mobile-app-with-react-native-and-babel-490363ec59) using babel resolver to set the root of the project and use only the components that are needed for the app.

something like this:

```
const brandPath = `./App/brands/${process.env.APP_BRAND}`;

console.log(`Bundling for the brand: ${process.env.APP_BRAND}`);

module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      ['module-resolver', {
        root: ['./App', brandPath, './App/brands/default']
      }]
    ]
  };
};
```

However, I get a bundle of all files that are included in the project even if I use `require('./reallyLargeImage.png') somewhere in one project. It will always be the same size.

Is there any solution to white labelling a RN application that could build and bundle only the necessary resources for specific config? Is targets/falvours the only way?

Answer (score 1):

There is a babel plugin for this: `babel-plugin-rn-white-label`, it looks old, but it's something. You can reach from [here](https://github.com/csath/babel-plugin-rn-white-label).

If you decide to use this plugin, you can specialize assets per app. For example, you have 3 apps (a, b, c), on every app you want to use a different image, just save images as image.a.jpg, image.b.jpg, image.c.jpg. Babel automatically pick when building the app. Let say if a and b using same image, you can use image.jpg and image.c.jpg because image.jpg will be used in default.

I didn't test it, but worth a shot.

Comment: thanks. I used it with react-native-ultimate-config and seems like it works good.